# Groovy: How can I from a method implementation access variable/object defined outside of the class?

Tags: groovy

The following code segment demonstrate my problem:

```
import java.util.timer.*  

s = "Hello"
println s
class TimerTaskExample extends TimerTask {  
        public void run() {  
            //println new Date() 
            println s 
        }  
}  

int delay = 5000   // delay for 5 sec.  
int period = 10000  // repeat every sec.  
Timer timer = new Timer()  
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTaskExample(), delay, period)
```

In my implementation of TimerTaskExample, I'd like to access s which is created in the "global" script scope. But I got the following trace:

```
Hello
Exception in thread "Timer-2" 
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: s for class: TimerTaskExample
at         org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:50)
at     org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.GetEffectivePogoPropertySite.getProperty(GetEffectivePogoPropertySite.java:86)
at     org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callGroovyObjectGetProperty(AbstractCallSite.java:231)
at TimerTaskExample.run(ConsoleScript2:8)
```

I tried google around, but couldn't find a solution.

Thanks a lot!

Yu SHen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although s (without the def) is defined in the binding, it is not accessible in a class you define in the script.
To get access to s in your TimerTaskExample class, you can proceed as follows:

```
class TimerTaskExample extends TimerTask {  
    def binding
    public void run() {  
        println binding.s 
    }  
}  

new TimerTaskExample(binding:binding)
```

Comment: Passing around bindings outside of a DSL context is asking for trouble, IMO. Better to design things correctly than to resort to such a blunt instrument.

Answer (score 1):

Groovy doesn't have a "global" scope per se; IMO it's cleanest to keep such "globals" in a class, defined as static finals, as in Java:

```
public class Constants {
  static final String S = "Hello"
}

println Constants.S
class TimerTaskExample extends TimerTask {  
  public void run() {  
    println Constants.S  
  }  
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried your method. It worked for my case. I also learned that variable/object defined in script does not automatically become global, which I assumed. I wish there is a more comprehensive tutor of Groovy. With its closeness to Java, I find it hard to fine one.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're using a Groovy script.

The only things a method has access to are:

- Attributes defined by the base class
- The dynamic properties defined by the MetaClass
- The *binding*

Scripts allow the use of undeclared variables (without `def`), in which case these variables are assumed to come from the script’s *binding* and are added to the binding if not yet there.

```
name = 'Dave'
def foo() {
    println name
}

foo()
```

For each script, Groovy generates a class that extends `groovy.lang.Script`, which contains a main method so that Java can execute it. In my example, I have only one class:

```
public class script1324839515179 extends groovy.lang.Script {
    def name = 'Dave'
    def foo() {
        println name
    }
    ...
}
```

What's happening in your example? You have two classes and the binding variables are in the Script class. TimerTaskExample doesn't know anything about `s`:

```
public class script1324839757462 extends groovy.lang.Script {
    def s = "Hello"
    ...
}

public class TimerTaskExample implements groovy.lang.GroovyObject extends java.util.TimerTask {
    void run() {
        println s
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks! But I thought that by writing "s="Hello" in the script scope without "def", it would be part of the binding? But it's not. I'm still confused about how the binding is constructed.

Comment: Check this: [Scoping and the Semantics of "def"](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Scoping+and+the+Semantics+of+%22def%22)